# Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) is not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:051b]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at e0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I tried almost everything I saw about it but it still same. I am using Lenovo G570. Help me. And also I tried most of things in here[Installing Broadcom Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) but still there is no wifi.

```
rfkill list all

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver you should be using for that card is b43 firmware.
Do this in a terminal `sudo apt purge wl`  Then this `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer` Reboot wifi should be working.

Comment: I tried. It didn`t work.

Comment: issue the following command rfkill list and post the results

Comment: You can see the result of rfkill list at the last part of the question.

Comment: this shows that your wireless card is turned off by a hardware switch.  there will be either a real switch or a combination of keys on my laptop it was F2 key.  Yours may be different